# Neofetch having trouble displaying information on Ubuntu Server 22.10

Tags: server, raspberrypi, 22.10

I installed Ubuntu Server 22.10 on my Raspberry Pi and somehow `neofetch` is not working properly. It's as if part of the information has been truncated and is therefore not displayed in the terminal.

[image]

Do you know why this happens ? Is it a scrollback issue ?

Comment: It would be interesting if you could try with a screen and monitor directly to the RasPi (output to TTY1). Or try another terminal application, and see if it's still an issue. I can't reproduce the issue using either WeTTY (Web) or Hyper (Electron) terminal apps.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, i plugged the RasPi directly into a monitor and i get the same issue. I also tried using xfce4-terminal via ssh and get the same result